# android using expandable list view with how to adding images to my child items

Tags: android, imageview, expandablelistview

i am creating android application that use expandable listview  with adding images by extending **BaseExpandableListAdapter**.

so i want to add to each child Item an image **(a flag)** .

can anyone help me to add to my code these images ??

**this is the app*
[image]

## parent_view.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textViewGroupName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="#009999"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSelectHandleLeft="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

## child_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#99D6D6"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:context=".ExpandableListMainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/childImage"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="#1919A3"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## MyExpandableAdapter

```
package com.devleb.expendablelistdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

    // constructor
    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents,
            ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
    // Implement this method as per your requirement

    // method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
    // Implement this method as per your requirement

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

        // get the textView reference and set the value
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

## ExpandableListMainActivity

```
package com.devleb.expendablelistdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class ExpandableListMainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    // Create ArrayList to hold parent Items and Child Items
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object > childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        // Set the Items of Parent
        setGroupParents();
        // Set The Child Data
        setChildData();

        // Create the Adapter
        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems,
                childItems);

        adapter.setInflater(
                (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
                this);

        // Set the Adapter to expandableList
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    // method to add parent Items
    public void setGroupParents() {
        parentItems.add("Africa");
        parentItems.add("Asia");
        parentItems.add("Europe");
        parentItems.add("North and Central America");
        parentItems.add("South America");
    }

    // method to set child data of each parent
    public void setChildData() {

        // Add Child Items for Fruits
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Algeria");
        child.add("Côte d'Ivoire");
        child.add("Côte d'Ivoire");
        child.add("Cameroon");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Flowers
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Australia");
        child.add("Japan");
        child.add("Iran");
        child.add("Korea Republic");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Animals
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Belgium");
        child.add("Croatia");
        child.add("France");
        child.add("Greece");
        child.add("Netherlands");
        child.add("Russia");
        child.add("Switzerland");
        child.add("Bosnia and Herzegovina");
        child.add("England");
        child.add("Germany");
        child.add("Italy");
        child.add("Portugal");
        child.add("Spain");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Birds
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Costa Rica");
        child.add(" Mexico");
        child.add(" Honduras");
        child.add("USA");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Birds
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Argentina");
        child.add("Chile");
        child.add("Ecuador");
        child.add("Brazil");
        child.add("Colombia");
        child.add("Uruguay");

        childItems.add(child);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package com.devleb.expendablelistdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private HashMap<String,ArrayList<ChildItem>> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems;

    // constructor
    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents,
            HashMap<String,ArrayList<ChildItem>> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
    // Implement this method as per your requirement

    // method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
    // Implement this method as per your requirement

    @Override
    public ChildItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childItems.get(parentItems.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childItems.get(parentItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return parentItems.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ChildItem child = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

        TextView textView = null;
        ImageView imageView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

        // get the textView reference and set the value
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        textView.setText(child.mTitle);

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childImage);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(child.mImage);

        // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }
}

public class ChildItem
{
       public String mTitle;
       public Bitmap mImage;
       public ChildItem(String title,Bitmap imageBitmap)
       {
           this.mTitle = title;
           this.mImage = imageBitmap;
       }
}
```

Comment: so where  is the images that i want to display it beside the child Items ??  can you explain your answer little more??

Comment: in your getChildView method you will need to load the image id from XML file and then draw the image into it .. you will find it in the getChildView

Comment: Okk i will try that  and I will get back to you hope that will work to stop bothering you with my questions

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience i want to help you all the way :)

Comment: i try it your answer but it did not work can you display the hall structure of the code of the project ?? because it make  me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnChildClickListener in your Activity and implemet this method..

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

       //Add new chid data in your list (ex ArrayLis or Array whatever you use)
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // BaseExpandableListAdapter's adapter...


    return true;
}
```

Is it work work for you?